# Adjustments to tikz graph of equations; label position, delete numbered axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I have a graph that is almost exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how to make the adjustments I need to make it perfect.

Here is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 12cm, compat = newest}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=left, axis y line=  
left, xlabel=x, ylabel=y}} %  the middle would produce the axis with four quadrants, and the left or right would result in only one quadrant.  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[my style]  

\addplot[domain=0:10] {x^2} node[pos=0.9,left]{$C_2x^2$}; % the domain signifies the range for the graph  
\addplot[domain=0:10] {7*x^2} node[pos=0.9,left]{$C_1x^2$}; 
\addplot[domain=0:10]{(5*x^2)+2*x} node[pos=0.9,left]{$f(x)$};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

which produces the following graph:
[image]

I'd like to adjust the positioning of the `$C_{2}x^2$` label so that it's slightly above it's graph instead of on it. I also need to remove the numbers on the axes completely, and on the x axis have a single point marked as `$k=1$` at `$x=1$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm, compat=newest,
    my style/.append style={
        axis x line=left, 
        axis y line=left, 
        xlabel=x, 
        ylabel=y, 
        yticklabels={}, 
        xtick={1},
        xticklabels={$k=1$}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[my style]  

\addplot[domain=0:10] {x^2} node[pos=0.9,above left]{$C_2x^2$}; 
\addplot[domain=0:10] {7*x^2} node[pos=0.9,above left]{$C_1x^2$}; 
\addplot[domain=0:10] {(5*x^2)+2*x} node[pos=0.9,above left]{$f(x)$};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: would you happen to know how I could add this graph to an enumerated list? When I try just putting the code in after \item the whole graph is above the number in the list. I want it to be below the number so that there is a clear delineation between the graph and the contents of the previous item in the list.

Comment: You have to change the tikzpicture baseline. Try to add `name=ggg` to the `axis` options, and then add `[baseline=(ggg.north west)]` as options to the `tikzpicture` environment. There's a chapter in the pgfplots manual with all the possible anchors (I'm not at a computer now... Answering by memory only).

Comment: @J.O'connor ...although that should be a new question...